# Does YouTube's Upload Deeplinking Support Parameters on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, youtube, deeplink

From within a Unity (game engine) app running under iOS I invoked authentic YouTube app's uploading view by simple doing this:

```
Applicaiton.OpenURL("http://youtube.com/upload");
```

Let it not scare you that the deeplink looks like a URL. It still invoked the native app and not goes to Safari.

It's all good and works perfect however I need more control. I need to precompose the movie's title, description and most importantly skip the movie selection view but point YouTube to a specific file.

Are there more arguments/parameters in YouTube's deeplinking scheme?

Comment: Thank you so much! I know it's not helpful to your question but I was looking for the deeplink to the uploading view in the app and for some reason this, after too much searching was the only place I found it.